# Install keeping data

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I have been keeping the '/home' directory on a separate partition for so long that I have forgotten what happens with '/home' as part of the '/' partition.

If /home is just part of / in the same partition and I install Ubuntu from CD to replace another distribution like Mint, can I do this without destroying the general data and the user settings in /home?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you install Ubuntu, your data in /home will be preserved, separate partition or not.

> Since Hardy it is possible to reinstall Ubuntu without losing the content of the /home folder (the folder that contains program settings, internet bookmarks, emails and all your documents, music, videos and other user files). **This can be done even if /home is not on a separate partition.**

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation

If you install another distro, Fedora, Mint, Debian, you will loose your data in /home if it is not on a separate partition.

Either way, if you value your data, back it up.

You can, of course, delete everything outside of /home , shrink the partition, and use it as a new home.

Personally, I give each distro a unique /home directory and use a data partition.

Comment: Thanks. I needed to know this so I could discuss it with someone.   You are absolutely right to stress doing a backup first! I  think there is a big advantage to a separate partition for /home - I had it on a separate disk at one point so I could change my os with no risk atall to my data (I unplugged the data disk when I was doing it!) My present computer hasn't really got room for two disks unfortunately.