# How to keep my data when re-installing ubuntu

Tags: partitioning

I have a laptop with Ubuntu installed and used the "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" option which means my system now only has 2 partitions: main and swap partition.

Now I need to install a new system,but want to keep some important data. I think the solution is creating a new partition a copy important data into that partition. But I don't know exactly what to do because I am new to Linux.

Comment: @bummi: please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/586859/revisions)  Don't just correct spelling, but also the grammar and increase the readability...  ;-)

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/a/454886/16395, you can retain your `/home` even if in the same partition since a lot of releases... And to the OP: *Backup*. **Always**. Before doing anything. The simple fact you have to ask this question mean you have a problem. Backup!

Comment: @CarlH not an exact duplicate. We should merge http://askubuntu.com/questions/19808/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-keeping-my-data-intact and http://askubuntu.com/questions/454877/install-keeping-data ...